# Add class active to the li when respective section is on screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a single page. I have min four sections on my page. I have to add the `active` class to the li tag on the menu when scrolling at the bottom with the respective section. For example, If about us section is on the screen then add class active to the li tag. If the gallery section is on the screen then add active class and remove the active class from the previous li.

I have to change the color and adding the bottom border to the active menu list. I don't want to use any plugin.

This is an example. It's adding the class active and changing the color of nav list
 https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

Is it possible to use jQuery?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.smothscrollclass a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.headerMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d9a6a6;
}

.anchorLinks ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.anchorLinks ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.anchorLinks ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.anchorLinks ul li.active a {
  color: #ffef00;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.WrapperInner {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

section {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}

section p {
  color: #fff;
}

.aboutus {
  background-color: #ec7063;
}

.service {
  background-color: #a569bd;
}

.gallery {
  background-color: #5dade2;
}

.contactus {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="mainInner bg_white">
    <div class="linkWrappers">
      <header class="headerMenu">
        <div class="anchorLinks smothscrollclass">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutus">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactus">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>

    </div>

    <div class="WrapperInner ">
      <section class="aboutus" id="aboutus">
        <h2>About us</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </section>
      <section class="service" id="service">
        <h2>Service</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


      </section>
      <section class="gallery" id="gallery">
        <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </section>
      <section class="contactus" id="contactus">
        <h2>Contact us</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </section>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi follow up the below snippet what I do here is made an one function called ***activateLink*** and I gave ID to links and clicking the link I add an active class to that particular li with the help of jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $('.smothscrollclass a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});

function activateLink (link,section) {
if(section){
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' : $("#"+section).position().top
    },function(){    
       $( ".active" ).removeClass( "active" )
       $("#"+link).addClass("active");
    });
}else{
 $( ".active" ).removeClass( "active" )
 $("#"+link).addClass("active")
 
}
 
}

function checkSectionExistance (sectionId,linkId) {
 var element = document.querySelector('#'+sectionId);
 var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

// checking for partial visibility
 if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
   $( ".active" ).removeClass( "active" )
 $("#"+linkId).addClass("active")
 }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 
  checkSectionExistance('aboutus','about-link')
  checkSectionExistance('service','service-link')
  checkSectionExistance('gallery','gallery-link')
  checkSectionExistance('contactus','contact-link')
  
     
  
 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.headerMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d9a6a6;
}

.anchorLinks ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.anchorLinks ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.anchorLinks ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.anchorLinks ul li.active a {
  color: #ffef00;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.WrapperInner {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

section {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}

section p {
  color: #fff;
}

.aboutus {
  background-color: #ec7063;
}

.service {
  background-color: #a569bd;
}

.gallery {
  background-color: #5dade2;
}

.contactus {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
a{
cursor:pointer
}
.active {
border-bottom:1px solid white
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="mainInner bg_white">



    <div class="linkWrappers">
      <header class="headerMenu">
        <div class="anchorLinks smothscrollclass">
          <ul>
            <li><a id='home-link' onclick="activateLink('home-link')">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id='about-link' onclick="activateLink('about-link','aboutus')" >About</a></li>
            <li><a id='service-link' onclick="activateLink('service-link','service')" >Service</a></li>
            <li><a id='gallery-link' onclick="activateLink('gallery-link','gallery')" >Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a id='contact-link' onclick="activateLink('contact-link','contactus')" >Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>

    </div>

    <div class="WrapperInner ">
      <section class="aboutus" id="aboutus">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </section>
      <section class="service" id="service">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


      </section>
      <section class="gallery" id="gallery">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </section>
      <section class="contactus" id="contactus">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </section>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

let me know if it's helpful

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: It's not working..It's working on click. I have to add on scroll class

Comment: ok can you please briefly explain on what event you wanted to set it active

Comment: This is the  example: https://preview.uideck.com/items/essence-demo/slider.html

Comment: ok, I got you so it shows the activated link but does not scroll to the respective section. give me some time I will resolve it

Comment: I updated the code above now it's working there was just a silly mistake of id duplicity. try it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216135/discussion-between-user9437856-and-ali-asgher-badshah).

Comment: @user9437856 did you check it

Answer (score 0):

with pure js you need to use `document.body.scrollTop;` to define how much was scrolled then remove style active from all li-s and add to the current or just manually for each remove the previous `for(let i = 0;i<liClass.length;i++){liClass[i].classList.remove("active")}` then add to the current targetting it by ID or unique class, works fine for me for jQuery is the same just `$("body").scrollTop()`

Comment: Can you help me with some examples for more understanding?

Comment: Wait a second I will add a new answer with a link to example

Comment: I added a new answer that would help I'm sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded a bit now everything is crystal clear ;)

For scrolls I used pure html just add ID to the element where you want to scroll and add `<a href="#theIdOfElement">`

the classes I did with jQuery as you asked

2nd EDIT:

```js
let  x=0;
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $("a").click((e)=>{
    //Removes class active from all a-s and all divs
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $("div").removeClass("active");
    //Adds only to clicked one
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    
    //Adds class active to divs that contain the text on which you clicked
    $("div:contains("+ $(e.target).text() +")").addClass("active");
  });
$(document).scroll(()=>{
    $("p").text( $(document).scrollTop());
        if($(document).scrollTop() >= 970){
        //If you want to get style permenent remove line below
    $("div").removeClass("active");
    $("#contacts").addClass("active");
  }
      else if($(document).scrollTop() >= 508){
     //If you want to get style permenent remove line below
    $("div").removeClass("active");
    $("#about").addClass("active");
  }
  else if($(document).scrollTop() >= 8){
     //If you want to get style permenent remove line below
    $("div").removeClass("active");
    $("#home").addClass("active");
  }


  });
})
```

```css
/*This is for smooth scrolling*/
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.big {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.active {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div style="position:fixed;display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;width:100%">
  <p id="demo">0</p>
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About Us</a>
<a href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
</div>
<div class="big" id ="home">Home</div>
<div class="big" id ="about">About Us</div>
<div class="big" id ="contacts">Contacts</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my description again. For example, check this image https://prnt.sc/t1fzz3 I am on service section so I have to change the color of service in the menu.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. You have to check Ali snippet so that you will get idea whar i am asking.